# System.UnexpectedException: Implementation restriction: activity aggregate relationships only allow security evaluation for non-admin users

Tags: trigger, exception

I have trigger which references openactivites and activityHistory objects. This trigger seems to work fine for all admin users but fails for non admin users

Here is the error message i get

> caused by: System.UnexpectedException: Implementation restriction: activity aggregate relationships only allow security evaluation for non-admin users when sorting on ActivityDate ASC, LastModifiedDate DESC for OpenActivity or ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC for ActivityHistory

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the class been called from the trigger and which was declared using a `with sharing` clause. Changing to `without sharing` resolved this error.